# Проблемы со слайдером (iView)

Tags: jquery, javascript

Не масштабируется изображение.Сам слайдер масштабируется 100% от "выделенного" места.Но суть в том, чтобы изображение находящиеся внутри хотябы сжималось до размера слайдера(не говоря уж про расширение).Но этого не происходит.Вот ссылка на сайт-[КЛАЦ](http://beri-dari.org/).В чем может быть проблема?

P.S.Вот сайт [слайдера](http://pcvector.net/scripts/slideshow_and_scroller/413-iview-adaptivnyy-jquery-slayder.html).Просто у меня уже паранойя. А я уверен что ошибка(может быть даже опечатка) детская. Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В одном диве пересеклись стили с bootstrap'а и стили самого слайдера.